# How to detect when user pressed the "allow" when user location is requested

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, location, cllocation

I am creating an app which uses the user's current location. At first run, after the user is prompted to allow or deny the app to use it's location, I want to do stuff when the user pressed the "allow" button. Is there a way to detect when the user has pressed the "allow" button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

You can use below delegate method to detect the user is authorized location or not. If user allowed the location, then it will returns status `.authorizedAlways` or `.authorizedWhenInUse`.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have direct access to that alert.

If the user click on "Don't Allow" then CLLocationManager will call **locationManager:didFailWithError:** on its delegate. The error domain will be kCLErrorDomain and the error code will be kCLErrorDenied.

you can check the status whethter user allowed or not.

```
let notificationType = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types
        if notificationType?.rawValue == 0 {
            self.openPushNotificationDialog() //user denied or don't allowed
        }
```

Official link for notification https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unauthorizationstatus

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3X**

you can click authorizedalways allow and deny then call this method and get some information about this.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
}
```